# SKMaps, Android landscape orientation issue

Tags: android, orientation, landscape, skmaps

I am using SKMaps (Skobbler) to develop an Android app in Eclipse.

I have an application which displays a map, has 2 buttons, can find routes to a point on the screen I tap on and initiate the navigation the SDK provides.

My problem is when I change the orientation of the device the app just closes. It does not give me any error message so I cannot identify the source of the issue.

The demo application provided handles the orientation of the device easily. I noticed that when I turn it around in the LogCat a message is displayed saying:

```
05-09 12:22:37.560: D/SKMaps(7866): MapRenderer----onSurfaceChanged width = 720 height= 1134
```

My application simply closes with the last message being:

```
05-09 12:22:37.745: D/SKMaps(7866): SKCurrentPositionProvider----stopped receiving position updates
```

I cannot find where in the demo application the code to handle orientation is. Does anyone have any idea where I could be going wrong.

ps. I have declared in my Manifesto my activity as:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.aatana.mymapproject.MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I found out if I get rid of my onDestroy method it works - it changes according to portrait / landscape.

Here is what I have in onDestroy:

Comment: super.onDestroy();
currentPositionProvider.stopLocationUpdates();
SKMaps.getInstance().destroySKMaps();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: But that is the code the demo app uses and it does not have any problem with the orientation. Is it necessary I leave it there or I can proceed from where I am now?

Comment: Still having problems with orientation or did you manage to solve them?

Comment: SKMaps.getInstance().destroySKMaps(); android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

I still dont know whether any of these 2 lines is important. I have currently removed them and the orientation changes. Do I need to keep any of them?

Comment: Could you provide the details about what Android version are you targeting? E.g.    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" /> (Or better, provide the whole manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

In the demo project, the MapActivity has overriden its onDestroy:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        currentPositionProvider.stopLocationUpdates();
        SKMaps.getInstance().destroySKMaps();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
```

You need to delete the line that kills the process:

```
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```